# Get DataTaken From .HEIC photos VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, photo, exif, heic

I'm trying to read the date on which a .heic photo was taken but without success.

```
image = New Bitmap(foundFile)
Dim propItems As PropertyItem() = image.PropertyItems
pic_time = image.GetPropertyItem(&H9003)
DateHour = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pic_time.Value, 0, pic_time.Len - 1)
Month = DateHour.Substring(5, 2)
Year = DateHour.Substring(0, 4)
image.Dispose()
```

Like this i can read .jpg exif information but not the .heic

I need to do this for create a software that sort photos based on the date the photo was taken.

Someone can help me for read the date of the .heic photos??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That format is not supported by GDI+. You can use [ImageMagick](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick) (there's a .Net wrapper provided as a NuGet Package), or you could also use [WIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-lh) (not easy if you never used it before). The decoder is not listed in the supported Codecs, but there's a (quite) limited support. There's also the `Cloudmersive.APIClient.NET.DocumentAndDataConvert` NuGet packge. It's an API, though (it also requires an auth token).